# What Android permission maps to "Device ID & call information?"

Tags: android

Here is a list of Android permissions: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

A recent update to an app is asking for "Device ID & call information" but I cannot figure out why the app is requesting this. Figuring out what the permission constant is seems like a good start, but I don't see any obvious permission for "Device ID & call information."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this permission group corresponds specifically to the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. You can find additional information here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/605/why-do-so-many-applications-require-permission-to-read-the-phone-state-and-ident